# "CLR detected an Invalid Program" when using Enumerable.ToDictionary with an extension method

Tags: c#, linq, clr, extension-methods

A colleague has passed me an interesting code sample that crashes with an `InvalidProgramException` ("CLR detected an Invalid Program") when run.

The problem seems to occur at JIT time, in that this compiles fine but throws the exception just before the method with the "offending" line is called - I guess as it is being JIT'd.

The line in question is calling `Enumerable.ToDictionary` and passing in a `Func` as the second argument.

If the `Func` argument is fully specified with a lambda it works; if it is specified as a method group, if fails. Surely these two are equivalent?

This has me stumped (and the colleague who discovered it!) - and it certainly seems like a JIT error.

**[EDIT: Sorry - I got the pass and fail cases the *wrong way round* in the code sample - now corrected (description above was correct)]**

Does anyone have an explanation?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test.Try();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static readonly int[] integers = new[] { 1, 3, 5 };
    public static void Try()
    {
        var line = new Line { A = 3, B = 5 };

        // PASSES
        var dict = integers.ToDictionary<int, int, decimal>(i => i, i => line.Compute(i));

        // FAILS
        //var dict = integers.ToDictionary<int, int, decimal>(i => i, line.Compute);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", dict.Select(kv => kv.Key + "-" + kv.Value)));
    }
}

public class Line
{
    public decimal A;
    public decimal B;
}

public static class SimpleCompute
{
    public static decimal Compute(this Line line, int value)
    {
        return line.A*value + line.B;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, on my local install, your "PASSES" line fails too

Comment: It's working fine on my (v4.0, x86) box - what version of .NET are you running, and what architecture?

Comment: Interesting! If you remove the extension method (ie put SimpleCompute as an instance method on Line) does it work? It does for me if I do this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your bug, which .Net version are you using?

Comment: It fails for me on .Net 4.0 on WinXP 32 bit and for my colleague on .Net 4.0 on Win7 64 bit

Comment: @Jon Skeet & lukas - It seems like Marc Gravell is getting the problem too, but not you two. To my knowledge there haven't been any service packs or other updates for .Net4 that could explain the difference have there?

Comment: @RobLevine: VS11 preview installation perhaps? (I haven't installed it on my netbook, but have on my home laptop, so I can check that tonight...)

Comment: Running the code in LinqPad throws the InvalidProgrammException (Win7, x64) when i uncomment the PASSES code. But i cann´t compile the code in VS2010, cause the second extension method is not defined or has invalid arguments.

Comment: @JonSkeet - thanks - that would be great. I'm going to try it on a few different machines to see if I can identify a pattern to the ones it fails on and the ones it passes on. Thanks.

Comment: I use win 7x64 .Net 4.0 Client Profile and it works fine also with 3.5

Comment: @Jehof - thank you - I labelled the pass and fail cases the wrong way round - DOH. Corrected now.

Comment: @RobLevine: Ah - that would explain everything. It fails for me too now...

Comment: sorry about that - last minute annotation gone wrong!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Compiler bug.

For info, I have the async CTP, which might be related; `csc` reports: 4.0.30319.440

Seems to be a difference between:

```
public static void TryTwo() // fails
{
    var line = new Line {A = 3, B = 5};

    var dict = integers.ToDictionary<int, int, decimal>(i => i, line.Compute);
    Console.WriteLine("TryTwo complete");
}
public static void TryFive() // works
{
    var line = new Line { A = 3, B = 5 };

    Func<int, decimal> func = line.Compute;
    var dict = integers.ToDictionary<int, int, decimal>(i => i, func);
    Console.WriteLine("TryFour complete");
}
```

so let's look in reflector:

```
.method public hidebysig static void TryTwo() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 4
    .locals init (
        [0] class Line <>g__initLocal6)
    L_0000: newobj instance void Line::.ctor()
    L_0005: stloc.0 
    L_0006: ldloc.0 
    L_0007: ldc.i4.3 
    L_0008: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Decimal::.ctor(int32)
    L_000d: stfld valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal Line::A
    L_0012: ldloc.0 
    L_0013: ldc.i4.5 
    L_0014: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Decimal::.ctor(int32)
    L_0019: stfld valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal Line::B
    L_001e: ldsfld int32[] Test::integers
    L_0023: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32> Test::CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate8
    L_0028: brtrue.s L_003b
    L_002a: ldnull 
    L_002b: ldftn int32 Test::<TryTwo>b__7(int32)
    L_0031: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32>::.ctor(object, native int)
    L_0036: stsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32> Test::CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate8
    L_003b: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32> Test::CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate8
    L_0040: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<!!1, !!2> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::ToDictionary<int32, int32, valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>, class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<!!0, !!1>, class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<!!0, !!2>)
    L_0045: pop 
    L_0046: ldstr "TryTwo complete"
    L_004b: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    L_0050: ret 
}
```

vs

```
 .method public hidebysig static void TryFive() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 4
    .locals init (
        [0] class Line line,
        [1] class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal> func,
        [2] class Line <>g__initLocal9)
    L_0000: newobj instance void Line::.ctor()
    L_0005: stloc.2 
    L_0006: ldloc.2 
    L_0007: ldc.i4.3 
    L_0008: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Decimal::.ctor(int32)
    L_000d: stfld valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal Line::A
    L_0012: ldloc.2 
    L_0013: ldc.i4.5 
    L_0014: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Decimal::.ctor(int32)
    L_0019: stfld valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal Line::B
    L_001e: ldloc.2 
    L_001f: stloc.0 
    L_0020: ldloc.0 
    L_0021: ldftn valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal SimpleCompute::Compute(class Line, int32)
    L_0027: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal>::.ctor(object, native int)
    L_002c: stloc.1 
    L_002d: ldsfld int32[] Test::integers
    L_0032: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32> Test::CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegateb
    L_0037: brtrue.s L_004a
    L_0039: ldnull 
    L_003a: ldftn int32 Test::<TryFive>b__a(int32)
    L_0040: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32>::.ctor(object, native int)
    L_0045: stsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32> Test::CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegateb
    L_004a: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32> Test::CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegateb
    L_004f: ldloc.1 
    L_0050: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<!!1, !!2> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::ToDictionary<int32, int32, valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>, class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<!!0, !!1>, class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<!!0, !!2>)
    L_0055: pop 
    L_0056: ldstr "TryFour complete"
    L_005b: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    L_0060: ret 
}
```

If you look in the broken version, it **only loads one delegate**. Compiler bug, basically:

```
L_0023: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32> Test::CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate8
L_0028: brtrue.s L_003b
L_002a: ldnull 
L_002b: ldftn int32 Test::<TryTwo>b__7(int32)
L_0031: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32>::.ctor(object, native int)
L_0036: stsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32> Test::CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate8
L_003b: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32> Test::CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate8
L_0040: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<!!1, !!2> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::ToDictionary<int32, int32, valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>, class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<!!0, !!1>, class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<!!0, !!2>)
```

all of the above is "check whether the cached `i => i` exists; if not create it; then load it". It **never does anything** with the second delegate. Consequently, there aren't enough values on the stack to make the method call.

Comment: Thanks Marc. Your description explains the StackUnderflow error that PEVerify reported on the assembly too (I probably should have mentioned that in the original question). Much appreciated!

Comment: @Rob just to add: this has been passed along to the appropriate channels for fixing.

Comment: Thanks again Marc - I was just wondering what to do about that, but you've sorted it. Again, very much appreciated.

Comment: Is there an incident number or somesuch for this issue being logged with Microsoft? We are keen to track it. Thanks.

Comment: @Rob no, but you could log it on connect if you want such

Comment: FYI: logged on Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727156/clr-detected-an-invalid-program-when-using-enumerable-todictionary-with-an-extension-method

Comment: Apparently, this bug is fixed with VS 2012 (RTM) +.